# Why SQL Server stored procedure selecting encrypted data into variable fails

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted, xact-abort

Stored procedure that selects data from encrypted column (Always Encrypted) into variable fails with an error

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

if `XACT_ABORT` is set to on.

Removing `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` line makes the stored procedure work perfectly, but it is unclear how it is related.

Completely removing variable also fixes an error.

Environment:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Enterprise (64-bit) Service Pack 2 with CU2 (13.0.5153.0): latest build at the moment.
- Microsoft Windows NT 6.3 (15063)

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SomeStoredProcedure]
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE @EncryptedValue VARBINARY(4096);

    SELECT TOP 1
        @EncryptedValue = [someencryptedcolumn]
    FROM
        [sometable];

    SELECT @EncryptedValue

    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Table declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE [sometable]
(
    [someencryptedcolumn] [varbinary](4096)
                          ENCRYPTED WITH
                          (
                            COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK1],
                            ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Randomized,
                            ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256'
                           )
                           NULL
)
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO [sometable] ([someencryptedcolumn])
VALUES (NULL)
```

Call the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [SomeStoredProcedure];
```

Error:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 29
>   Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 29
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

I found no references on how XACT_ABORT and Always Encrypted related.

I also checked for SQL Server logs but found no additional information on the issue.

**Update**:

[Link to the registered SQL Server bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34960006-sql-server-stored-procedure-selecting-encrypted-da)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the product. You should first try installing the latest SP/CU to see if it has already been fixed and if not report it to Microsoft.

I can also reproduce this on SQL Server 2017 RTM. I haven't tried installing the latest CU to see if that improves things.

It isn't specific to `XACT_ABORT`. You also see the same with other set options. Such as

- `SET DATEFIRST 5`
- `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.

When these are present it ends up calling `sqllang.dll!CEnvColEncryptionKey::XretSchemaChanged` twice and the second time around it ends up trying to dereference a null pointer and fails with an `Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000`.

The call stack when the error is thrown (by `SELECT @EncryptedValue`) is as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Martin! It is reproducible on the SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 2 (SP2) with CU2: 13.0.5153.0 (latest build). I will report it to Microsoft.

Comment: bug report. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34960006-sql-server-stored-procedure-selecting-encrypted-da